# Access AngularJS module config from directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'd like to be able to define **ui-router** states from markup, using directives. The directive's children would be the template for the state, for example:

```
<state name="foo" url="bar">
  <div>I'm the template</div>
</state>
```

To do this I need to access `$stateProvider` when I'm processing a directive. I tried this in the link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('Can we have $stateProvider here?');
            angular.module('MyApp').config(function($stateProvider) {
                console.log('yes');
            });
        }
```

The function passed to config doesn't get called this way.
How can I access `$stateProvider` when I'm processing the directive (in link or compile function)?

Comment: I think the problem with this approach is, that you have to use config before app module is bootstrapped, but all the link functions are actually executed after that

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I'm still wondering if it can be done and an idea just came up: have a root module that processes the markup and  initializes my actual app module with that information. I will try this and add it here if no better solution comes in.